# How to block a port for specific time?

Tags: windows-7, port, blocking

I want to block a port for a specific time duration, say 1 am to 3 am.  I can add a rule to built in firewall but this blocks the port all the time. Is there any way to do this for only a specif period of time ?

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not doable unless you make your own VBS script to automate with Task Scheduler. For which you need to implement Windows Firewall API. If oyu make a script post it. It would be of immense help to others.

Comment: +1 for controlling with Task Manager suggestion. It doesn't need to be VBS script though, PowerShell scripting would work, but easiest may be to use a couple batch files and Windows' [`netsh`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709) command.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution. First add a rule to block desired application in the firewall. Then the rule can be enabled or disabled using the command:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="MyRule" new enable=yes
```

This can be added to a script that periodically checks time and enables/disables MuRule accordingly. I could not find sleep command in batch script and I don't know PowerShell so I wrote a simple c++ program.

```
#include<ctime>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{//code for hiding console
    HWND window; 
    AllocConsole();
    window = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(window,0);

    Sleep(60*1000);// 1 min delay
    time_t now;
    struct tm *current;
    now = time(0);
    while(1)
    {
    current = localtime(&now);
    if(current->tm_hour>=22||current->tm_hour<=6) // 10 pm to 6 am
        system ("netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=\"MyRule\" new enable=yes");
    else
        system ("netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=\"MyRule\" new enable=no");
    Sleep(10*60*1000);// 10 min delay
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile using gcc and run at logon using Task Scheduler with Admin Privilege.

Comment: I *think* there's some inconsistancy between 'MyRule' "MuRule" and "Murule" there. I'm not sure tho, I don't read C well enough

Comment: Corrected. I had different name in original program. Made mistake while changing name.